# Reactive Spring component to Produce Kafka messages with Avro Schema

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, avro

I'm trying to find a simple Reactive Spring component to Produce Kafka messages with Avro Schema, but I'm not sure if there is something that I can use to do that, any ideas?
Thanks in advance!